# How to make 2 different spans change color on hover

Tags: html, css

### Issue

I have a **< span>** with text inside that says "View Portfolio", but i also have a **< span>** that is a Glyphicon. When the user hovers over any of the **< span>** tags i want both of them to turn black.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="maincontentportfoliotitle col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
        <span class="portfolioLink">View Portfolio</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
        <span class="portfolioLink glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"/>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.portfolioLink:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

At the moment only the **< span>** tag I hover over changes color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to wrap them under one wrapper, and then when the wrapper is being hovered, you'll color both spans.

```css
.portfolioLink:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="portfolioLink">
<div class="maincontentportfoliotitle col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
        <span>View Portfolio</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an aside to the other answers, if you don't want everything in the container to change color, you can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/haccej6L/

```
<div id="container">
<span class="type1">Blah</span>
<span class="type2">Foo</span>
<span class="type1">Blah</span>
</div>
```

```
#container
{
  background-color: white;
}

#container:hover .type1
{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the div that wraps around the spans the class your giving them. This is because what your doing makes it so each span turns black when hovered. If you give the class to the div that surrounds both spans, it will apply the hover to both, yet make it shared.

So

```
<div class = "portfolioLink">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Would work with your class portfolioLink

Answer (score -1):

```css
div:hover + div > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontentportfoliotitle col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
  <span class="portfolioLink">Make me over!</span>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 text-center">
  <span class="portfolioLink glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">View Portfolio</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably `div:hover span,div:hover + div > span` as I think he wants both to change. This is better as it doesn't request another HTML element. But the problem is, if you hover over "View Portfolio" then "Make me over" won't change and CSS doesn't provide a previous sibling selector I don't think.